# Import an SVM model in PMML to Java or Python?

Tags: python, r, svm, libsvm, pmml

**Short question**: is there a PMML interface for Java, Python or any other major programming language that supports SVM models?

**Background**: I have trained an SVM model in R using the `ksvm` function from the `kernlab` package. Now I would like to use this model in a different piece of software. To export it from R, I think I could use PMML (Predictive Model Markup Language) via the `pmml` package for R.

However, I can't find any library for Java, Python, or basically any language that allows for importing such a model. [The Data Mining Group](http://www.dmg.org/products.html) lists quite a few PMML interfaces, but these are mostly specific tools for statistics. There is also the [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) general library, but it is not clear how this can be used to migrate models from one to another interface.

Comment: [Weka](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/PMML+Support+in+Weka) may be able to import SVM models.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd: It seems like it is, although I haven't found any documentation yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the model you trained in any language. There is an example for Python [Reinitializing learned linear models with scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642545/reinitializing-learned-linear-models-with-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Zementis ADAPA scoring engine to deploy your model and them access it through web-services. From my experience, ADAPA is also available as a Java library and so you can code against its Java API. Hope this helps.

Comment: This Java library sounds like it is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I can't find anything about it on the internet; it looks as if ADAPA is only offered as a web service. Do you have more information?

Answer (score 0):

A library called "Pattern" translates PMML models into Cascading apps in Java. Then you can run model scoring on Hadoop or within other Java apps.
 https://github.com/Cascading/pattern

There's a SVM impl for Pattern -- being rewritten for the latest update to the library. Check on the developer email list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pattern-user

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the Cascading apps are only for scoring models, which I can also do in R. I want to write an application using the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Weka both as an Java API or as standalone tool, which works well for PPML with some classifiers.
Check these classes in weka API: weka.classifiers.pmml.consumer.PMMLClassifier and weka.classifiers.pmml.consumer.SupportVectorMachineModel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the JPMML (Java Evaluator PMML API) will do what you want.