# Importing PMML 3.2 model to Debug in Python and convert to 4.2

Tags: python, xml, pmml

I have a PMML model written in PMML 3.2 and I need to debug the code to run it properly.

I have looked at partykit in R, but I would like to understand if I can import an XML PMML file into Python and check it is formatted correctly for PMML 4.2?

I did not create the original model , but need to debug the syntax correctly and would like to do it in a open source tool.

Package like Augustus etc. seem to be able to generate PMML easily, but I need to import this model to check its syntax and then convert it / upgrade it to 4.2

[Import an SVM model in PMML to Java or Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874969/import-an-svm-model-in-pmml-to-java-or-python) thread is a good start, but it only focuses on Java and adapa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can download the PMML specification [here](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/pmml-4-2.xsd) and use any online tool, like [this](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VzKoP5MrJp8), to validate your PMML file.

You can find the list of PMML producers and consumers in this [link](http://dmg.org/pmml/products.html). You may use [KNIME](https://www.knime.org/downloads/overview), an open source drag & drop application which supports Python, R, and Java, to import your model and check if it is recognized by KNIME.

You may also use [ADAPA](http://zementis.com/products/adapa/) to further examine your PMML file to see if it contains a valid model. ADAPA is available on AWS (Amazon Web Services) as SaaS but you can use it for free for 14 days, I believe. It's the most comprehensive PMML validator, convertor, and executer.